# Find item index in list

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

This is a very simple question but I can't seem to understand why I am not getting it.

```
def listindex():
    li = ['a', 'e', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'e']
    for x in li:
        if x == 'a':
            print(li.index(x))
```

Result:

```
0
0
0
```

Expected Result:

```
0
2
5
```

Although it iterates over all the item I only get first item index, why is it? Also advise even though its pretty simple.

Comment: [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) - *"`s.index(x)` index of the **first occurrence** of x in s"*

Comment: @ilaunchpad Dont worry much about *internet points*. It is the learning which is important. Cheers.

Comment: ...because it's trivially answered by reading the existing documentation, or [previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/176918/3001761), or just `help(list.index)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm sorry not everyone understands everything from the documentation.  If everyone only followed the documentation this place would be only solving questions for rocket scientist.

Comment: It's not like this is a complex edge case, or the documentation is even slightly unclear here. SO is not for every question, and we expect [a fair bit of research before asking](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3001761). Maybe you read the documentation and didn't understand it - that's OK, but then **mention that** and be specific about what's eluding you. You even acknowledge that it's not a good question **in the question** - *"This is a very simple question... Also advise even though its pretty simple."* Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @jonrsharpe I said it's simple because the logic is fairly simple even for me. And I explained which part I didn't get. I stated the items are iterated and I thought it should give me the index which seems pretty simple I don't seem to get. Anyways thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`index` returns the index of the first element only. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

> Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead. When you iterate using *enumerate* you can access the element and its index on the loop:

```
>>> li = ['a', 'e', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'e']
>>> for i,element in enumerate(li):
...     if element == 'a':
...        print(i)
... 
0
2
5
```

Comment: @maccinza I'd like to keep `i` for `index` as it has always been recommended. Thanks for the rest. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

```
li = ['a', 'e', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'e']
```

Use List Comprehension:

```
[i for i, x in enumerate(li) if x=='a']
```

Output: `[0, 2, 5]`

Answer (score 0):

Use keyword enumerate()  this will generate a counter from 0 to N.

```
for i, x in enumerate(li):
```

So `i` will contain the indexes for `li`.